# App crashes when chiledviewcontroller button clicked

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

am creating a ipad application where i need to show a ChildViewController inside a ParentViewController's View with below code its working perfect.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   FavViewController *aViewController = [[FavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.mainView addSubview:aViewController.view];
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

When this `favViewController` load into the `self.MainView` of parent view all controls inside childViewController showing ok but when i click on UIButton the app is crashing. below is log for the crash.

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMapTable myAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8093170'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1733012 0x1558e7e 0x17be4bd 0x1722bbc 0x172294e 0x156c705 0x4a02c0 0x4a0258 0x561021 0x56157f 0x560222 0x4cfb1d 0x4cff02 0x4add4a 0x49f698 0x25fddf9 0x25fdad0 0x16a8bf5 0x16a8962 0x16d9bb6 0x16d8f44 0x16d8e1b 0x25fc7e3 0x25fc668 0x49cffc 0x255d 0x2485 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: `'-[NSConcreteMapTable myAction:]: unrecognized selector` means that somewhere you have a pointer to an NSConcreteMapTable and you tried to call "myAction" using it.  Remember, the type of a pointer does not assure that the object pointed to is that type -- you can very easily screw things up and get the wrong object type into a pointer.

Comment: i found solution i need to add the below code '[self addChildViewController:aViewController];'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a memory management bug caused by misuse of `UIViewControllers`.

The `FavViewController` created in your `-viewDidLoad` is not retained and so will be deallocated shortly after you leave that method.

You have created a view with a controller, bound actions from controls inside that view to the controls, allowed the controller to be destroyed, and then attempted to fire one of those actions by tapping on a button.

The error you see is because an instance of `NSConcreteMapTable` now happens to occupy the memory space that once contained your `FavViewController`.

In addition you are expected not to arbitrarily nest views which belong to `UIViewController` subclasses like that. If you need to do so you should be using the "container view controller" methods to manage those child controllers. `- addChildViewController:` is one of those methods and happens to solve the problem because the parent view controller now retains a reference to the child controller so it will not be deallocated.